# Sort javascript object based on date keys

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a JavaScript object that looks like follows

```
testObj = {
    1/10/2015: {},
    2/10/2015: {},
    3/10/2015: {},
    4/10/2015: {},
    29/09/2015: {},
    30/09/2015: {}
}
```

Now, I'm trying to sort this such that the dates are arranged by date in increasing order. For that i've done the following

```
const orderedDates = {};
Object.keys(testObj).sort(function(a, b) {
    return moment(moment(b, 'DD/MM/YYYY') - moment(a, 'DD/MM/YYYY')).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
}).forEach(function(key) {
    orderedDates[key] = testObj[key];
})
rangeObj = orderedDates;
```

This however is not sorting the dates at all. It still returns the same exact object as `testObj`. How do I sort the object based on date keys?

Comment: Here's the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: @mguimard But the use of `const` would indicate [ES6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties), not ES5

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This line returns a *string*:

```
moment(moment(b, 'DD/MM/YYYY') - moment(a, 'DD/MM/YYYY')).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

But the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description) method requires an *integer* value, so you need to compare the actual dates instead:

```
Object.keys(testObj).sort(function(a, b) {
    return moment(b, 'DD/MM/YYYY').toDate() - moment(a, 'DD/MM/YYYY').toDate();
}).forEach(function(key) {
    orderedDates[key] = testObj[key];
})
```

However you need to be aware that in ES5, the order of keys in an object was not guaranteed by the spec - although most browsers did iterate the keys in insertion order. In ES6 however, you can be guaranteed that if you iterate your objects keys they will be in order.

So `console.log(orderedDates)` may not show the keys in your expected order, but `Object.keys(orderedDates).forEach(function(date) { console.log(date); });` will work as expected.

```js
var testObj = {
    "1/10/2015": {},
    "2/10/2015": {},
    "3/10/2015": {},
    "4/10/2015": {},
    "29/09/2015": {},
    "30/09/2015": {}
};
var orderedDates = {};
Object.keys(testObj).sort(function(a, b) {
    return moment(b, 'DD/MM/YYYY').toDate() - moment(a, 'DD/MM/YYYY').toDate();
}).forEach(function(key) {
    orderedDates[key] = testObj[key];
})
Object.keys(orderedDates).forEach(function(date) {
   document.body.innerHTML += date + "<br />"
});
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it without the moment library. It will work for all js frameworks.

```
var testObj = {
  "3/10/2015": {},
  "2/10/2015": {},
  "1/10/2015": {},
  "4/10/2015": {},
  "29/09/2015": {},
  "30/09/2015": {}
};
var ordered = {};
Object.keys(testObj).sort(function(a, b) {
  return (dateConverter(a) - dateConverter(b));
}).forEach(function(key) {
  ordered[key] = testObj[key];
});

/* Convert DD/MM/YY to date object */
function dateConverter(date) {
  var dateParts = date.split("/");
  var dateObject = new Date(+dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, +dateParts[0]); 
  return dateObject
}
/* ordered return now                                               
  "1/10/2015": {},
  "2/10/2015": {},
  "3/10/2015": {},
  "4/10/2015": {},
  "29/09/2015": {},
  "30/09/2015": {} */
```

Comment: for me ordered object was still not ordered after the forEach loop. Within the loop, however, the elements were in order. I guess it is because you are assigning testObj to a dictionary, which does not guarantee order

Answer (score 3):

Without moment, easier sorting can be achieved if the date is in the format 'YYYYMMDD' with any separator.

```js
const testObj = {
  "1/10/2015": {},
  "2/10/2015": {},
  "3/10/2015": {},
  "4/10/2015": {},
  "29/09/2015": {},
  "30/09/2015": {}
};

const orderedDates = {};
Object.keys(testObj).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.split('/').reverse().join('').localeCompare(b.split('/').reverse().join(''));
}).forEach(function(key) {
  orderedDates[key] = testObj[key];
})

console.log(orderedDates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `moment` package, you can use:

```
const yourFormat = 'DD/MM/YYYY'
const sortDateMoments = (dates) => {
  const moments = dates.map(date => moment(date, yourFormat))
  moments.sort((a, b) => a.isBefore(b) ? 1 : -1)
  return moments
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved without using moment, `console.log()` could still mess up the order but iterating the keys would work like a charm, Yeah perks of ES5.

```js
    const sortDatesObject = (unsortedDatesObject) => {
        const sortedObject = {};
        const reverseDate = date => date.split('/').reverse().join('/');
        Object.keys(unsortedDatesObject)
            .map(date => reverseDate(date))
            .sort((a, b) => { return new Date(a) - new Date(b) })
            .forEach((date) => {
                sortedObject[reverseDate(date)] = unsortedDatesObject[reverseDate(date)]
        });
        return sortedObject;
    }

    testObj = {
        "1/10/2015": {},
        "2/10/2015": {},
        "3/10/2015": {},
        "4/10/2015": {},
        "29/09/2015": {},
        "30/09/2015": {}
    }
    
    Object.keys(sortDatesObject(testObj)).forEach(key => console.log(key));
```